# How is the concept of cultural encounter treated in the short story “One Out of Many”?

Tags: short-stories, character-analysis, v-s-naipaul

In the story "One Out of Many" by [V.S. Naipaul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V._S._Naipaul), how is the concept of cultural encounter treated? I have a few questions about that:

- Is the author aware of the cultural encounter theme?
- How does he manifest that awareness? Are the main characters, mainly Santosh, aware of the cultural encounter theme?
- What clues does he provide of such awareness, if any?
- How does the usage of “clothes” highlight the theme of cultural encounter?
- How does the usage of “contrasts” (present versus past, now versus then, here versus home) throughout the short story help in highlighting the theme of cultural encounter?

Comment: Hey there, welcome to the site. Your questions being somewhat specific, I suspect that this is a question from a school/homework assignment. [That's not necessarily a problem](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/560/481), but you have to make sure you follow some rules. Most importantly, make sure you don't violate your school's academic integrity requirements; if this is a project you're supposed to figure out on your own, you shouldn't necessarily seek help. If you *are* allowed to ask others for help, you should make sure you cite the answers here appropriately to avoid plagiarism.

Comment: (For your own good -- teachers can detect plagiarism by running your work through a program that will check it against material that others have written on the internet. It's generally not a smart move to plagiarize.) Also, if the questions you ask here belong to someone else, you may need to quote them to avoid plagiarism (for Stack Exchange rules, not school rules). Anyway, I hope you are able to find the information you're looking for. Good luck!

Comment: no no it is not an assignment i am a graduate , I'm trying to study literature by myself and i found these questions on a story which i was reading and i can't seem to answer them :)

Comment: Okay, cool. I was thrown a little because you placed quote marks around "clothes" and "contrasts." If you can, you should probably [edit] your post to include a link (or citation) to the place you found those questions. That's only fair to the people who asked them originally, and also might help other users here find an answer for you more easily.